# GridView does not display on ASP.NET page when uploaded to IIS 8.0 server

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, iis, gridview

I have written a script (aspx+aspx.cs pages) that connects to a .xls file and reads from  several ranges of Excel cells, consecutively, and displays their content in multiple, consecutive, GridViews, one for each range of cells.

The problem is that the code works fine when debugging it on my Visual Studio Community Edition 2013, but when I upload it to the Production Server, which is meant to be a IIS Server 8.0, none of the Gridviews shows up.

I have got some labels on the .aspx page, these are being displayed, but the GridView does not.

I have impersonated the application in web.config with a user that should have access to the resource on the server. If I connect to the server with that user (same I used to impersonate the app) and use the same path to address the Excel file, then I can open/view the Excel file.

I tried multiple versions to write down the path, none seems to work. Even `C:\Name_of_the_Excel_File.xls` (after saving the Excel file in the root of C:\ of the server that hosts IIS) is not working. Seems that the aspx app can not read from the Excel file in any of the cases when hosted on IIS. e.g.:

```
 <connectionStrings>
    <add name="xls" connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=\\srv***\l***\9*****\9***\****M.xls;Extended Properties=Excel 8.0"/>

  </connectionStrings>
```

Do you have any recommendation about what else could be causing this behaviour (why GridView does not show up when uploading the app on the IIS Server)?

Comment: have you tried to check if File.Exists is true in your code-behind?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thank you, anyway.

even if you did not get me a solution on this one, I came to the stackoverflow.com community for lots valuable assistance when I needed it.

I found the solution on my own this time:

- it was related to the OLEDDB providers on the IIS 8.0 Production server
- complete reference of the solution is here: http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/280/solved-the-microsoft-ace-oledb-12-0-provider-is-not-registered-on-the-local-mac

namely I had to

> Locate the setting "Enable 32-bit Applications" of the application pool used by the website and change it from **False to True:**